# Syncing radiobuttons/checkboxes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have simple radio buttons. One section has parent level items and the other child items. If the user selects the parent item and if the parent has only one child item then the child item should automatically be selected.

This sounds simple but I don't think I'm thinking this right.

Right now I have hard-coded my function to work on the first parent item like so:-

```
test1 : ko.observable(),
test2 : ko.observable(),
syncSelections: function(){
    this.test2("banana");
}
```

where "banana" is the value of the child item. My hard-coded [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu9jx/).

Comment: How are you storing the parent/child relationship between the items?

Comment: Let's say JSON.
[{"fruit": { item: "banana"}}, {"vegetable":{item: "tomato"}]

Comment: Ok.  I asked because I don't see that type of structure in your question or in your sample fiddle.  So you have a "fruit" object and a "vegetable" object -- both contain an "item" property.  And whenever the "fruit" is selected, you want banana selected?  Likewise, if "vegetable" is selected you want tomato selected -- and banana de-selected?

Comment: Yes, when fruit is selected then "banana" should be selected and same for "vegetable" and "tomato" too. But "fruit" and "vegetable" option doesn't have any relation so one should not be deselected when the other is clicked. So, to answer your question for the last question, no, if "vegetable" is selected then "banana" should not be deselected.

Comment: I would start by writing the javascript object(s) that define your data structures, their "selected" status along with methods to modify their status.  Then, work on the data-binding with knockout